# Pandas-datareader not able to pull from yahoo finance- unable to read url with response text in error saying "our engineers are working on it"

Tags: yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I was just working on a simple project trying to pull stock data from yahoo finance using pandas-datareader and the code send back an error which I will post below:

```
pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=1577869200&period2=1648799999&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history
Response Text:
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n  <html lang="en-us"><head>\n  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n      <meta charset="utf-8">\n      <title>Yahoo</title>\n      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimal-ui">\n      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">\n      <style>\n  html {\n      height: 100%;\n  }\n  body {\n      background: #fafafc url(https://s.yimg.com/nn/img/sad-panda-201402200631.png) 50% 50%;\n      background-size: cover;\n      height: 100%;\n      text-align: center;\n      font: 300 18px "helvetica neue", helvetica, verdana, tahoma, arial, sans-serif;\n  }\n  table {\n      height: 100%;\n      width: 100%;\n      table-layout: fixed;\n      border-collapse: collapse;\n      border-spacing: 0;\n      border: none;\n  }\n  h1 {\n      font-size: 42px;\n      font-weight: 400;\n      color: #400090;\n  }\n  p {\n      color: #1A1A1A;\n  }\n  #message-1 {\n      font-weight: bold;\n      margin: 0;\n  }\n  #message-2 {\n      display: inline-block;\n      *display: inline;\n      zoom: 1;\n      max-width: 17em;\n      _width: 17em;\n  }\n      </style>\n  <script>\n    document.write(\'<img src="//geo.yahoo.com/b?s=1197757129&t=\'+new Date().getTime()+\'&src=aws&err_url=\'+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+\'&err=%<pssc>&test=\'+encodeURIComponent(\'%<{Bucket}cqh[:200]>\')+\'" width="0px" height="0px"/>\');var beacon = new Image();beacon.src="//bcn.fp.yahoo.com/p?s=1197757129&t="+new Date().getTime()+"&src=aws&err_url="+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+"&err=%<pssc>&test="+encodeURIComponent(\'%<{Bucket}cqh[:200]>\');\n  </script>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n  <!-- status code : 404 -->\n  <!-- Not Found on Server -->\n  <table>\n  <tbody><tr>\n      <td>\n      <img src="https://s.yimg.com/rz/p/yahoo_frontpage_en-US_s_f_p_205x58_frontpage.png" alt="Yahoo Logo">\n      <h1 style="margin-top:20px;">Will be right back...</h1>\n      <p id="message-1">Thank you for your patience.</p>\n      <p id="message-2">Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.</p>\n      </td>\n  </tr>\n  </tbody></table>\n  </body></html>'
```

I looked all over forums to find a solution and saw this was a problem from July of 2021, but I am getting it now. I employed all the solutions, updating my pandas-datareader to make sure it was the right version, even pip uninstalling and pip installing all the packages and libraries again. Nothing seems to be working. No forums solutions work. Oddly enough when I run the scripts through command prompt it works and is able to pull data but not in my IDE which is Visual Studio Code. Does that mean the problem is with Visual Studio Code? Please help as this project is due very soon. I will keep monitoring this post to answer any follow up questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are [fairly recent, open issues](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/916) in the pandas datareader project regarding this error.

That is, the following snippet yields the observed errors:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("SPY", start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")
```

Here are two solutions. If you want to stick to the pandas datareader, you can try out the code below, which was adapted from [this post](https://aroussi.com/post/python-yahoo-finance):

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()

# download dataframe using pandas_datareader
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("SPY", start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")
```

Or even easier, the pure `yfinance` version:

```
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download("SPY", start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")
```